# GWT 2.0 Visual Layout Tools?

Tags: gwt, layout

Are there any tools that would assist us less artistic types in GWT 2.0 layout that use GWTxl?  I'm fairly CSS impaired and would like to see how my changes look "on the fly".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Free on-line editors for GWT:

http://bootdiskrevolution.com/gwtlab-1.0.2/Gwtlab.html - gwt-lab simplifies the development of GWT Composites. The tool uses a WYSIWYG approach to build the Composite's user interface, including its CSS rules. gwt-lab generates the Composite's Java code to include in the user’s favourite IDE, where business logic and event handling is added.

gwt-lab was developed using: Eclipse 3.4, Google Web Toolkit 1.6.4, and gwt-dnd (2.5.6) for Drag and Drop

http://works.sen-sei.in/gtg/ (GWT Theme Generator) - a simple theme generator for GWT. This application generates a GWT theme based on the color you choose. This application is free for use. No guarantees (implied or otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

[GWT Designer](http://www.instantiations.com/gwtdesigner/) seems like the kind of thing you're looking for.

Comment: I've looked at their page before but they don't seem to support gwtXL (the new layout language) and are Java only.  Was I wrong?  Is there a document that covers this?

Comment: gwtXL? please link us, never heard of this. And GWT is supposed to be Java only ...

Comment: I'm not sure what GWTXL is (there are no relevant search results), but he might mean UiBinder, which constructs GWT UIs using XML files.

Answer (score 0):

Project [Vaadin](http://vaadin.com/home) is built on GWT and provides WYSIWYG designer.

There is also plugin for Eclipse - [GWT Designer](http://www.instantiations.com/gwtdesigner/). That is unfortunatelly commercial, but you can try it for free for 30 days.

But to be honest, web making requires knowledge of css - so you should start learning it ASAP - it's definitelly not difficult, just takes time. I've also been messing with those designers (as mostly GUI person) and it was always better when handwritten.

Back to your question, I use [GWT Eclipse Plugin](http://code.google.com/eclipse/) and If I am correct, you can see even CSS changes on the fly, can't you?

Comment: No.  You have to load the application.  And yes, knowing CSS is handy, but the implementation of said is not always intuitive so a WYSIWYG designer is extremely helpful.

Comment: Vaadin also appears to be a platform built on GWT and not just a designer.

Comment: yes, but vaadin also has a designer ...
using vaadin is the only free way how to use visual designer, AFAIK (but on the other hand, you aren't using pure GWT though)